# System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The role 'user' was not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I'm a bit out of my depth with this so if anyone can help I would be so grateful. I have a website written using asp.net/VB with SQL for the database. On that server and wanted to duplicate it to be able to change it and turn it into a different site. My developer set me up a new database and copied necessary sql files across. When trying to register a new account I get the error: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The role 'user' was not found but sometimes the site says the email address I'm trying to register already exists.. The database is empty though so I think I have something wrong in my WebConfig file where it's probably trying to connect to the old database ? I have copied the webconfig from that site too and simply renamed the "application Name=" parts.. Below shows the database and then the webconfig. Thank you so much for any help at all.

[image]

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" name="freebeeAuth1" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="259200" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" domain=".freebeepoints.com" path="/" />
</authentication>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/freebee" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="/freebee" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="/freebee" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/freebee" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I now have this connected and storing info to the database, Still need to know why I'm getting ths error though.. Roles are not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy over your website to a new location to have a copy of the same website, you should not change the ApplicationName in the asp.net membership stuff. Just change the connectionstring to make sure you're connecting to the right db.

Also make sure you're keeping the same machinekey element.

Hope this helps...